# Fetch last written message offset number from kafka

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm producing messages to a topic named as `default`.

My producer partition is `RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA`, When I'm using unassigned partition, how can I get the offset of the last message pushed to `default` topic.

I don't need offset of consumer, I need offset of the last published message.

I need the offset for crash recovery, human intervention is not intended.

I need the offset using `librdkafka`, when my program starts back again, based on the offset, I will do some modifications to my program, so I need to fetch it through API only and when needed.

I don't think I can rely on callback,

consider I pushed my message, I received callback and my program crashed.

or

I pushed my message, I was about to poll and my program crashed.

I'm using C language `librdkafka` library.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using the delivery report of the producer.

One of the librdkafka example, [`rdkafka_example.c`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c), demonstrate this feature.

For example:

```
./rdkafka_example -P -b localhost:9092 -t testtopic -o report
% Type stuff and hit enter to send
hello
del: Success: offset 0
% Message delivered (5 bytes, offset 0, partition 0): hello
hello
% Sent 5 bytes to topic testtopic partition -1
del: Success: offset 1
% Message delivered (5 bytes, offset 1, partition 0): hello
^Cdel: Success: offset 2
% Message delivered (5 bytes, offset 2, partition 0): hello
```

You see for each message sent, the delivery report contains the offset the produced message.

Basically this example:

- sets `produce.offset.report=true` [[1]](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c#L608-L610)
- registers a delivery report [[2]](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c#L611)
- in the delivery report, access the offset field [[3]](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.c#L135)